# How to find an specific index in an R data table?

Tags: r, indexing

I'm working on an R project using a table of Covid-19 cases (columns are dates, files are countries) and I want to find the index of the first column in which the number of cases is non zero for a specific country.

The table is like this: [image: Table showing cases of Covid-19]

I know how to index the specific country: For example `i_arg <- which(rownames(datos) == "Argentina")`
and a specific date. But not a date that fulfils a specific condition based on the value it takes on a specific row and the rows before (as I want the index of the first column whose value for a specific row is the first one that isn't 0 in that specific row).

I know this has to be a silly question, but I couldn't find information on how to do this anywhere.

Here is the data for the first few countries as  MrFlick suggested:

> "1/22/20" "1/23/20" "1/24/20" "1/25/20" "1/26/20" "1/27/20" "1/28/20"
> "1/29/20" "1/30/20" "1/31/20" "2/1/20" "2/2/20" "2/3/20" "2/4/20"
> "2/5/20" "2/6/20" "2/7/20" "2/8/20" "2/9/20" "2/10/20" "2/11/20"
> "2/12/20" "2/13/20" "2/14/20" "2/15/20" "2/16/20" "2/17/20" "2/18/20"
> "2/19/20" "2/20/20" "2/21/20" "2/22/20" "2/23/20" "2/24/20" "2/25/20"
> "2/26/20" "2/27/20" "2/28/20" "2/29/20" "3/1/20" "3/2/20" "3/3/20"
> "3/4/20" "3/5/20" "3/6/20" "3/7/20" "3/8/20" "3/9/20" "3/10/20"
> "3/11/20" "3/12/20" "3/13/20" "3/14/20" "3/15/20" "3/16/20" "3/17/20"
> "3/18/20" "3/19/20" "3/20/20" "3/21/20" "3/22/20" "3/23/20" "3/24/20"
> "3/25/20" "3/26/20" "3/27/20" "3/28/20" "3/29/20" "3/30/20" "3/31/20"
> "4/1/20" "4/2/20" "4/3/20" "4/4/20" "4/5/20" "4/6/20" "4/7/20"
> "4/8/20" "4/9/20" "4/10/20" "4/11/20" "4/12/20"
>
> "Afghanistan" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 5 7 7 7 11 16 21 22 22 22 24
> 24 40 40 74 84 94 110 110 120 170 174 237 273 281 299 349 367 423 444
> 484 521 555 607
>
> "Albania" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 10 12 23 33 38 42 51 55 59 64 70
> 76 89 104 123 146 174 186 197 212 223 243 259 277 304 333 361 377 383
> 400 409 416 433 446
>
> "Algeria" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 5 12 12 17 17 19 20 20 20 24 26 37 48 54 60 74
> 87 90 139 201 230 264 302 367 409 454 511 584 716 847 986 1171 1251
> 1320 1423 1468 1572 1666 1761 1825 1914
>
> "Andorra" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 39 39 53 75 88 113
> 133 164 188 224 267 308 334 370 376 390 428 439 466 501 525 545 564
> 583 601 601 638
>
> "Angola" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4
> 5 7 7 7 8 8 8 10 14 16 17 19 19 19 19 19 "Antigua and Barbuda" 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 9 15
> 15 15 15 19 19 19 19 21 21
>
> "Argentina" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 8 12 12 17 19 19 31 34 45 56 68 79 97
> 128 158 266 301 387 387 502 589 690 745 820 1054 1054 1133 1265 1451
> 1451 1554 1628 1715 1795 1975 1975 2142

the file is called "data_covid19.txt" and is imported this way

```
datos <- read.table("data_covid19.txt", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

I want the index so I can select the data that I need like this:

```
datos[i_arg, first:last]
```

Where:

```
i_arg <- which(rownames(datos) == "Argentina")
last <- which(colnames(datos) == "3/29/20") #specific date
```

And `first` is the index of the column that fulfils the condition

Thanks!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Pictures of data are not helpful because we can't copy/paste the data to test. Better to include just a simple example data.frame in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data all has a common type and two variables. This is a strong indicator that it should be structured as a numeric matrix, NOT as a `data.frame` or `data.table`. Matrixes have better out-of-the-box support for rowwise operations than `data.frame` objects. Indeed, the primary advantage of `data.frame` objects and their cousins over matrixes is their support for heterogeneous data types, which you do not require.

If you are OK with your data being a matrix, this is trivial:

```
my_matrix <- matrix(
  data = c(0,0,1,0,5,2,1,2,3),
  nrow = 3,
  ncol = 3,
  dimnames = list(
    c("Albania", "Argentina", "Armenia"),
    c("2020-01-01","2020-02-01", "2020-03-01")
  )
)

> my_matrix

          2020-01-01 2020-02-01 2020-03-01
Albania            0          0          1
Argentina          0          5          2
Armenia            1          2          3

> match(TRUE, my_matrix["Argentina",] > 0)

[1] 2
```

If you insist on your data being a `data.frame` object or one of its cousins, more convoluted methods start becoming necessary. Your data has a pretty simple structure so you can just transpose it, but this is not really optimal.

```
my_data_frame <- as.data.frame(my_matrix)

> match(TRUE, t(my_data_frame)[,"Argentina"] > 0)

[1] 2
```